# Django won't connect to Redis Docker container

Tags: django, docker, redis

I've spent forever trying to connect my Django container to Redis while using Docker-Compose. After hours of changing Docker and Django configs and trying different ways to run everything, I finally figured out that Redis was broadcasting to the host.

These were the errors I was getting each try:

- Error 111 connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused.
- Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
- Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.

I finally ended up changing the Django IP config for Redis to the Docker host IP and it worked just fine...

Does anyone know of a way to configure everything so that Django looks for Redis on the internal Docker network rather than the external host?

FYI - I'm a total noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host name is what you call the container that runs Redis. For example, if your docker-compose contains something like this:

```
cache:
    image: redis:3.2.6
```

then, you need to set the configuration to connect to `cache:6379`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the below answer, the probable issue while using docker compose is referring to localhost directly. We must use the service name instead.

So if you are using in docker compose, redis like this:

```
cache:
  image: redis:7-alpine
```

Then in settings.py, refer to the service like this:

```
CACHES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": "redis://cache:6379/1", # Note the cache
            "OPTIONS": {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            },
        }
    }
```